# Dashed trend line with R plotly

Tags: r, plotly

How to get a dashed trend line with the `plotly` package ?
According to the documentation, it should be:

```
dat <- iris[,2:3]
colnames(dat) <- c("x","y")
p <- plot_ly(dat, x = x, y = y, type="scatter", mode="markers", name="data")
add_trace(p, x = x, y = fitted(lm(y~x, data=dat)), line = list(dash="dashed"), name="regression line")
```

But the trend line is solid.

Comment: Providing dash length in px is working. `line=list(dash=3)`. https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-line-dash

Comment: It seems that `"dashed"` is not a valid option for `dash` argument. It can be `"dash"`,`"dashdot"`,`"dot"` or `"solid"`. Read more here . https://plot.ly/javascript-graphing-library/reference/#line-dash

Comment: @neoFox You're right, it works with `"dash"`. But `dash=3` gives something strange (not pretty).

Comment: yeah, the spacing is not uniform when dash length is given.

Answer (score 8):

What you can do here is run a regression and then add the fitted line for the same in your code. The syntax for the same is:

```
add_lines(x= ~label1, y= fitted(fit1), name = "",
          line = list(color= c_yellow2, widthh=0.5, dash="dot"))
```